# Polymer.js Paper Tabs styling

Tags: html, css, polymer, material-design

I'm wondering how to implement a yellow, sliding `border-bottom` property as seen on example **C.** "The bar slides to the selected tab"
https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/components/paper-tabs/demo.html .

Inspecting the CSS, I didn't see a `border-bottom` property.

Has someone tried to recreate it or there any good resources on that?

Comment: Maybe I'm too late, but it's worth knowing, there's a full well designed catalog with Polymer 1.0 that you should check if not already done : https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-tabs?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=paper-tabs

Answer (score 0):

```
paper-tabs{
            --paper-tabs-selection-bar-color : #4286f4;
        }
```

Use this in  to change the color of the tab.